# How to download an image outside the document root with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

Our images are stored out of the document root, therefor we use a script to get it into the browser.

```
/prx/asset.php?tgt=<photo_filename>
```

I can display correctly the image in the web

```
$("#photo-editmodal").attr('src', '../prx/asset.php?tgt='+details.photo_saved_file);
```

The goal is be able to download that image.

I have been reading some references and the closest point I have achieved is doing a request through AJAX and then create an ObjectURL with the result, but (I think) since the stream data received, it is not a valid reference to create the ObjectURL.

Here it is my try:

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../prx/asset.php?tgt='+details.photo_saved_file,
                    method: 'GET',
                    xhrFields: {
                        responseType: ''
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);

                        var a = document.createElement('a');
                        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

                        a.href = url;
                        a.download = details.photo_saved_file;
                        document.body.append(a);
                        a.click();
                        a.remove();
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                    },
                    // error: function(data) {
                    //     console.log(data);
                    // }
                });
```

I get the message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

Anyone can help to get this done?

**EDIT**

I get rid of the ajax call and now I am doing the following:

```
$("#download_photo").attr('href', '../prx/asset.php?tgt='+photo);
$("#download_photo").attr('download', photo);
```

The issue I have now is it works on the scond time the button is clicked.
Any idea?

**EDIT 2**
It was much simpler than expected, still don't know why the link element can't be created with the help of ObjectURL, but I can assign the href when the "edit" modal is open and therefor the link with download attribute works at first click.

Comment: You know this is incredibly unsafe, right? The whole point of root containment is to prevent anything from exploiting an unknown vulnerability in PHP to ask for "some path that goes up a few `../`". After all, what's stopping someone from asking for `"../../../../../../etc/passwd"`? The proper solution here is to fix your setup and put the images in a dir under your document root, so you can safely serve up those files. And then you can use a cron job or dir-watcher (e.g. an .sh script, _not_ PHP) that can copy the images to `public/images` or something, and you're good to go.

Comment: This is not my scenario, I understand what you say, but it doesn't apply to my use case. Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more details in your post to explain why this isn't your scenario, because based on what you're written so far, it definitely is.

Comment: Nobody can ask for another folder, there is not a form input, neither the URL parses anything. I am implementing a button. Also, the OS is not *nix, so no way to get confidential files. Images are stored by another process and they are in the place they should be. Do you have an idea how to solve my problem ? How is it possible it works on the second click?

Comment: The form is irrelevant: cURL exists. And the URL is not something you fully control: PHP has had "magic URL behaviour" in the past, and there is zero guarantee that isn't still true, just even less well-known than the ones that got patched already. Also, the OS doesn't matter: someone can just ask for _all_ sentitives paths on _all_ operating systems, and one or more of them will work. So either teach the process that stores the images to put them in your public dir, or have copies made (however that makes sense) OR run a secondary internal-only server for image pass-through.

Comment: At the end it was much simpler, I fill the file to download before and then the HTML5 download attribute made the trick. My problem was solved. Security concerns are not much important for this case since it is an internal application. Also, the script which serves the file do some checks. Thanks for your time and concern.

Answer (score 0):

It was much simpler than expected, still don't know why the link element can't be created with the help of ObjectURL, but I can assign the href when the "edit" modal is open and therefor the link with download attribute works on first click.